# how can we extract data from amazon seller central business reports with sku-id,asin and date as the schema. Need a consolidated report

Tags: pandas, excel

extracting datasets with required schema from amazon seller:
sku-id
date
parent asin
child asin
page visits(visibility)

got 2 seperate reports, unable to consolidate them as there is no common schema.
The data is present in csv format

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.